# How to construct an IF statement to match only specific text

Tags: excel, search, text, formula

I am trying to figure out how to create an `IF` statement that returns true only if a cell contains a specific substring.

For example, say I am searching two cells for the substring `HVS0544-1`.

- First cell contains: `WBS HVS0544-1`
- Second cell contains: `HVS0544-154`

I want to return yes for the 1st cell, but no for the 2nd cell because it is not an exact match for the substring `HVS0544-1`.

I tried using this formula `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(M91964,N1365))`. However, it always returns yes when the substring `HVS0544-1` is present. So it is tricked by similar values like `HVS0544-154`.

Any hints for how I could improve my formula?

Comment: You could use the `EXACT` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. :)

```
=IF(RIGHT(N1365,LEN(M91964))=M91964,1,0)
```

Used the length of the formula to pick out only the ending and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This will help You Remember the `"Text"` must be in " "

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring;"HVS0544-1")); "Yes"; "No")
```

The Value will be only Yes or No , You may change that